# Getting the html "id" tag in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, getelementbyid

I am working on a UPS tracking macro and I basically used the code from: [UPS Automated tracking clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820892/vba-excel-ups-automated-tracking-clicking-a-button).

However, I cannot seem to extract the status of the shipment after I manipulate the code to my liking. Below is what I have and the error that I am currently running into.

> Run-time error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

Code:

```
Sub test()
' open IE, navigate to the website of interest and loop until fully loaded
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_US"

    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

' Enter a value in the "Number" text box
    ie.document.getElementById("trackNums").Value = "1Z12345E1512345676"

' Click the "Submit" button
    Set Results = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each itm In Results
        If InStr(1, itm.outerhtml, "Track", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            itm.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

' Click the "Shipment Progress" button
    Set Results = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each itm In Results
        If InStr(1, itm.outerhtml, "Shipment Progress", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           itm.Click
           Exit For
        End If
    Next

' Get the text from the "Shipment Progress Table" and assign to a variable
    Dim status As String

    Set doc = ie.document

    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    'tbltxt = doc.getElementsByTagName("pkgstep1").innerText
    status = doc.getElementById("tt_spStatus").innerText

    ' process the text as desired
    ActiveCell.Value = status

End Sub
```

This exact line that I am running into problems is:

```
status = doc.getElementById("tt_spStatus").innerText
```

Here is the screenshot of the `text` I want to pull from the tag.
[image: tag]

Comment: what happens if you `Set doc = ie.Document` _after_ the loop has finished loading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of lines above the line that errors, you have this line:

```
Do Until ie.readyState = 4
```

Change it to this:

```
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
```

Comment: Changed, but still gives me the `run-time '91'`

Comment: Are you sure? I got the same error on the same line with your code. The problem was that the page was not completely loaded (because .readyState is not reliable on its own) and so there was not yet an object with the specified ID available when the ensuing code tries to get it. Adding the reliable check that consists of both .busy and .readystate completely fixed your code here. Now it never errors.

Comment: That is so weird. I hope I am changing it correctly. I have `Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4 DoEvents Loop` Does that seem right?

Comment: Yep. That's correct... as long as that three lines of code.

Comment: Yea 3 lines. I might be missing a plugin? Changed code above.

Comment: There is nothing extra that you need. As long as you have IE on your machine this should work. I am getting the innerText for `tt_spStatus` into the status variable every time. It works.

Comment: I don't know why, but when i changed `status = doc.getElementById("tt_spStatus").innerText` to `status = doc.getElementById("tt_spStatus").innerHTML` it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad you got it going!